# HtmlPage.Window.Invoke not working for javascript function in separate js file

Tags: javascript, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I'm trying to call a js function from Silverlight using the HtmlPage.Window.Invoke method but it won't call a function contained in a seperate js file.

Anyone know why?

Cheers

AWC

Comment: The js file hosted by the same server?  Place the same function in the HTML page instead does that work? Calling some other function places directly in the page does that work?

Comment: it is part of the same project and is included correctly in the HTML

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the head section of your ASPX or HTML file to add the reference of your js file for the function to get called. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyFunctions.js"></script>
```